# How to explicitly tell user to wait until script finishes in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I need some advise accomplishing the action on the title o this thread; let me elaborate, I have a Spotfire analysis where the data to be used is controlled by a cascading set of drop-down menus, each one linked to a document property.
The way it works is that the user selects a value in the 1st drop-down, and in the background, a script runs that automatically limits the options available for the following drop-down menu. This behavior repeats in the second and third drop-down selectors. 
This works as expected. However, my problem is that a great number of operations ocurr in the background when these document properties change, such as recalculation of sevreal fairly large table merges, recalculation of a many columns on several other tables down the analysis, etc.
All of these take a long time to execute, and the problem is that the users end up looking an unresponsive screen while these actions take place.
What I need is a way to indicate the user that the analysis is not hung up and they just need to wait until the background operations complete before proceeding to make a selection on the next drop-down menu.
I've tried simple stuff as creating a document property that gets assigned a value as soon as the drop-down script is clicked on, and then the same property gets reset at the end of the script, using the property value to indicate that the script has or hasn't completed, but this approach doesn't work.

```
# Copyright © 2017. TIBCO Software Inc.  Licensed under TIBCO BSD-style license.

#
# Updates a dependent control, setting the value of the 
# dependent property according to the first valid value 
# for that property.
#
# This script should be configured to run when the independent
# control is changed
#
# Andrew Berridge, TIBCO Spotfire, July 2014, Revised September 2016

from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

#Updates one or more dependent property based on the selection made in another drop-down control
independentPropertyValue = Document.Properties[independentPropertyName]
Document.Properties["readyToDisplay"] = "No"

i = 0
for dependentPropertyName in dependentPropertyNames.Split(","):
    dependentPropertyName = dependentPropertyName.Trim()
    dependentValuesDataTableName = dependentValuesDataTableNames.Split(",")[i].Trim()
    dependentValuesDataTable = Document.Data.Tables[dependentValuesDataTableName]
    dependentPropertyName = dependentPropertyNames.Split(",")[i].Trim()
    dependentPropertyValue = Document.Properties[dependentPropertyName]
    dependentValuesColumnName = dependentValuesColumnNames.Split(",")[i].Trim()
    dependentValuesColumnCursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dependentValuesDataTable.Columns[dependentValuesColumnName])
    independentValuesCursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dependentValuesDataTable.Columns[independentValuesColumnName])
    firstValidValue = ""
    for row in dependentValuesDataTable.GetRows(dependentValuesColumnCursor, independentValuesCursor):
        independentValue = independentValuesCursor.CurrentValue
        val = dependentValuesColumnCursor.CurrentValue
        if independentValue == independentPropertyValue and val != "(Empty)" :
            if firstValidValue == "" : 
                firstValidValue = val
                break

    print "Setting value of dependent property " + dependentPropertyName + " to: " + firstValidValue
    Document.Properties[dependentPropertyName] = firstValidValue
    i += 1

Document.Properties["readyToDisplay"] = "Yes"
#print "readyToDisplay is " + Document.Properties["readyToDisplay"]
```

Any ideas on how to go about this problem?
In simple terms, I just need a way to indicate to the user that "stuff" is happening in the background after making a selection in any of the the drop-down menu selector, as well as notifying them when the system is ready for them to make the following selection and so on. 
Thanks

Mario Reyes

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this sample to add a progressbar while the script executes-

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-add-progress-bar-and-cancellation-option-when-executing-ironpython-scripts-tibco-spotfire